# Check whether query image exists in template database for matching purpose

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on hand vein recognition system and I have already extracted the white pixel coordinates of the thinned vein patterns for 10 images and have stored them in a notepad.

Now, I have a query image and I have extracted the coordinates for the thinned vein patterns.

From here, how do I proceed with the matching phase by checking whether this query image exists in the database and also generate a matching score.

Thank You

Comment: perhaps you should also add [tag:machine-learning] and [tag:computer-vision] tags to attract the right audience

Comment: [FEX: Miura et al. Vein extraction methods](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35716-miura-et-al-vein-extraction-methods). Also, this question is too vague and I think that by notepad you intend .txt or .dat

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing the coordinates in a text file, instead of a binary vein image for each hand image?  You could then use image comparison techniques.

Comment: @denver: In fact I am applying the 4 steps (image acquisition, preprocessing, processing and matching) of a biometric system. I have already worked out the binary vein image and perform feature extraction (i.e exraction of the vein pixel coordinates). From here, I need to perform matching to check whether a query image exist in my database. Thank You

Comment: I am following your questions about this topic from some time. Why are you storing pixels in notepad and then again checking whether the query image exists in the database or not? Why not check if an image has a match in the database? Feature extraction process will be useful if you want to match irrespective of some kind of distortion i.e. rotation, displacement etc.

Comment: @Parag : Ok, it seems to be a good idea but how do I proceed with it. Will I be able to generate a matching score at the end?

Comment: You have written "whether this query image exists in the database". So are you searching for exact match?

Comment: @Parag: Well, it is not necessary for it to be exact match. But it should be atleast >= 80%.

Comment: In that case, I am not sure how vein coordinates would help you. [This](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29280-fingerprint-matching-algorithm-using-shape-context-and-orientation-descriptors) might help.

Comment: @Parag: I have already browsed through it. However, it is not appropriate for me since it makes use of hough transform for detecting lines. In my case, Vein recognition system, the patterns consist also of curves (Curly patterns).

Comment: Could you give some additional details about what you are trying to do?  Are you looking for a second image from an existing patient?  Are you looking for identify some features an individual has?  It is difficult to give suggestions because it isn't clear where you are going with this.

Comment: To Everyone: I have added a new post with more details on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256908/how-to-perform-pixel-by-pixel-matching-to-check-whether-a-query-image-exist-in-t/16256992?noredirect=1#16256992) Please refer to it. Thanks

Comment: @user2265058: you should have just edited this same question instead of creating a near duplicate